# How to link Account with Event in a SOQL Query

Tags: soql, account, relationships, event, queries

I need a SOQL Query to List of Ids from **Account older than 14 years** and with **no Events in the Last 6 Months**.

I tried to "link" both requests with `whoId` relation on Event:

```
SELECT Id, CreatedDate
FROM Account
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT WhoId FROM Event WHERE StartDateTime > LAST_N_MONTHS:6)
AND CreatedDate < LAST_N_YEARS:14
```

Here is the log error :

```
Entity 'Event' is not supported for semi join inner selects
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You can't get the results in a single query statement, you need Apex to filter out the accounts with recent events.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
for(Account acc :[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Events WHERE StartDateTime > LAST_N_MONTHS:6) FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate < LAST_N_YEARS:14]) {
     if(acc.Events.size() > 0) {
         accounts.add(acc);
     } 
}
```

Comment: You may want to add a `LIMIT 1` to the inner query there. In the situation where you have an account with many (~200 or more) Tasks in the target timeframe, you'd get the "Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment" error when trying to execute `acc.Events.size()` unless you limit the number of returned children.